jdbc: Could not create connection to database server on Android Studio
I encountered the following problem: I am running MySql Server on a laptop (ip 192.168.1.10), I am creating applications in Android Studio that should connect me to a database on the same local network as the laptop, I run the applications on my phone, but I get error "Error message: Could not create connection to database server." But the most interesting thing is that the third-party application connects to the database via the same IP from my phone, but my application does not. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Button button;
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.10:3306/sakila", "boxapp", "12345"
                    )) {
                        Log.d("huyblya", "Connected to database");
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // Виводимо повний стек винятків
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        // Виводимо текстове опис помилки
                        Log.d("huyblya","Error message: " + e.getMessage());

                        // Виводимо код помилки
                        Log.d("huyblya","Error code: " + e.getErrorCode());

                        // Виводимо SQL стан
                        Log.d("huyblya","SQL state: " + e.getSQLState());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("huyblya", "No internet connection");
                }

            }
        });


huyblya com.example.connecttodb D  Error message: Could not create
connection to database server.

huyblya com.example.connecttodb D  Error code: 0

huyblya com.example.connecttodb D  SQL state: 08001


Perhaps this database doesn't quite fit here? Then which server database is better to use?
I tried to change the connection link, add parameters + searched half the Internet but did not want to connect to anything.
I enabled permission to use the Internet, as well as the JDBC connector.
Everything works via localhost or 127.0.0.1 from a laptop, but not from a phone(

Please read: JDBC vs Web Service for Android and ANDROID: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mysql/cj/MysqlType

The Class.forName() line hasn't been needed since 2006. Remove it.

This is quite likely a network layer and not an application layer problem; no route to host?
Make sure to enable the "LAN to WiFi bridge" or however it may be called in the router's web GUI (just see the manual). These are actually two different sub-nets, which may or may not be bridged.
You could try with "ADB WiFi" once, in order to see that the Android debug bridge also won't reach any destination on the wireless sub-net. That's one simple test to verify that suspicion.
Alternatively, for local development it may be of advance, to put the MySQL instance into the same sub-net as the Android emulator. This would then all be running on localhost in a virtual sub-net, with no router required, also very portable when installed on a notebook.
At least on MS SQL-Server, 08001 suggests to use IP v6 instead of IP v4. This may be unrelated, since it's MySQL, but it still points into the direction of a (local) network issue; which could be both, a missing network bridge or a server which won't accept IP v4 connections. You'll have to set this up properly outside of the IDE, before anything inside the IDE would function.

But what if I connect to the database from my phone, on the same local network, but through third-party applications from PlayMarket hiSql, and the connection is successful. Is it a network problem then?
